# When I run the code, it says "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kivy.uix.Label"

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.Label import Label

class invisible(App): 

    def build(self):

        return Label(text="Hello")

if __name__ == "__main__":
     invisibleApp().run()
```

Error comes from the third line.Cannot import name "label"

Comment: I think you want `from kivy.uix.label import Label` Note the uppercase `L` on the import of the class object.

Comment: I see you edited your code but there is still a mistake on the third line, it should read `from kivy.uix.label import Label` the module has a lowercase `l` the class object has an uppercase `L`.

Answer (score 1):

You want `kivy.uix.label`, not `kivy.uix.Label`.

```
    from kivy.uix.label import Label
```

always  remember to use lower case after `uix`

Eg
`kivy.uix.image`
`kivy.uix.button`
`kivy.uix.screenmanager`

Comment: I changed it to Label , no it says 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kivy.uix.Label''

Answer (score 0):

Rename your code name if you are using kivy.py